# Spring - WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring, been reading a whole lot but I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. I've included the relevant parts below... 
 
web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>display</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>display</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.p</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

display-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />   
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

displayController.java:

```
package com;
@Controller
public class displayController {

    @RequestMapping("/display")
    public ModelAndView displayName() {
        System.out.println("-- in handleRequest");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("display");
        user u = new user();
        u.setUsername("bob");   
        mv.addObject("user", u);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Now, as far as I know, this is what I think happens, but it isn't.. 
 
**1.** I go to a url "/user/display.p" 
**2.** Application looks in the web.xml, finds the url pattern "*.p" and notices it should be linked with the servlet display. Then an instance of DispatcherServlet is created and the context in display-servlet.xml is loaded. 
**3.** When display-servlet.xml is loaded, it notices the mvc:annotation-driven and does something (not really sure I understand that one yet, but I think I need it. Then, it notices the component-scan and scans through the "com" package, of which displayController is located. 
**4.** displayController is searched for annotations and it finds it is a controller, and also any url with "/display" in it should automatically trigger the displayName() function. 
**5.** [Somewhere in here things break...] 
**6.** Then, what SHOULD happen (but doesn't) is the view "display" should be loaded and the "/WEB-INF/jsp/display.jsp" should be loaded. However, no view "display" is found and I receive the error "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testing/user/display.p] in DispatcherServlet with name 'display'"

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the displayName() function getting called - i.e., is the "in handleRequest" message getting printed out?

Comment: What is the /testing/user in the url.  If you are accessing /testing/user/display.p form the browser then the RequestMapping should be for /testing/user/display

Comment: Why do you navigate to `/user/display.p` if your controller is mapped as `/display.p`?

Comment: Ahh, k axtavt is onto something here.. I just went to "/display.p" and it worked! I think I can figure out what I need from here, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
package com;
@Controller
public class displayController {

@RequestMapping("/user/*)
public ModelAndView displayName() {
    System.out.println("-- in handleRequest");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("display");
    user u = new user();
    u.setUsername("bob");   
    mv.addObject("user", u);
    return mv;
}
}
```

The dispatcher will delegate requests with the pattern *.p to the dispatcherServlet and the dispatcherServlet will delegate the /user/* requests to your method.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@RequestMapping("/user/display.p")` ?

Comment: No, it was never printing. However, from a comment on my main post I realized that in order to do what I want, I need to go to "/display.p" instead of "/user/display.p"

Comment: However, this suggestion by Aravind also makes my program work as intended (it just wasn't exactly what I was after) so I will accept it as the answer for those in the future!